# Calculating the probability of 2 for the sum of two dices, knowing that the sum will be even.

Tags: probability

I'm having a problem with calculating the probability of the followig scenario. I have two normal dices (6 sides a piece). I know that the sum of the two tosses is even. I want to know what the chance is that the sum of the two tosses is 2. In other words I want to calculate P(X = 2 | X is even). Where X is the sum of the points. I believe the answer should be 1/18 because there're 36 possible scenarios (1, 1) ... (1,6), (2.1) ... (6,6), from these 36 scenario's 18 are even. And only one of those gives 2 as the sum.

When I want to calculate this, I use P(A|B) = (P(A intersection B) / P(B)). I rewrite A intersection B to P(A)P(B) this however doens't result in 1/18. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's $2$ *dice*, I'll warrant.

Comment: Here $A\cap B=A$, hence $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$ where $A$ stands for $X=2$ and $B$ for $X$ is even.

Comment: Welcome to the math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see, e.g., 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: As for the question per se, the main problem is that the equality $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ only holds if $A$ and $B$ are independent. In this case, they aren't.

Comment: Thx for the help all, I'll go through the writing math documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A$ and $B$ are NOT independent, so $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A)P(B)$. Indeed, notice that if your sum happens to be $2$, then you automatically have an even sum. In set notation, this means that $A \subseteq B$, which tells us that $A \cap B = A$. Thus:
$$
P(A \mid B)
= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
= \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}
= \frac{1/36}{18/36}
= \frac{1}{18}
$$
as desired.